# Analysis of url

Tags: subdomain

```
hj.nm.google.com
```

How to you look at `hj.nm`,is it a server named `hj.nm`?
(What should `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` be?)

Comment: strictly speaking what you've posted isn't a valid url

Comment: @Mark, how do you figure? its possible for me to host a name record for hj.nm.domain.name on my DNS servers, its not a valid TLD but it can be hosted on a closed network.

Comment: a URL has to have a resource type (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url)

Comment: @Mark, my bad you are correct. I read into it what I wanted to read, it is a valid hostname, but not a valid url. My apologies. :)

Answer (score 3):

**In reality:**

`hj` is a subdomain of `nm.domain.name`
`nm` is a subdomain of `domain.name`
`domain` is a subdomain (technically) of `name`

**In PHP:**

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in this case might be `hj.nm.domain.name`
*This variable can be defined as anything if running on a virtual host*

If you reliably want the web address your PHP script is running at, I believe you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

Comment: Your understanding of $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is obviously wrong.

Comment: Can you explain "This variable can be defined as anything if running on a virtual host"?

Answer (score 1):

could be anything really, but subdomains could be usernames in the DB or, an arbitrary name to separate it from www.domain.name.

so no, it's not necessarily a server named hj.nm

Answer (score 1):

You can basically look at it in reverse:

- com - root name
- google - domain of root name
- nm - sub domain of "google"
- hj - sub domain of "nm"

As to the physical implementation, you cannot tell from the name given. It is possible to host com, google.com, nm.google.com, and hj.nm.google.com all on the same server as well as hosting hj.nm.google.com on more than one server.

Comment: My answer is still essentially correct if that is to be considered a valid DNS record (i.e. "host" name).